# How to read out one value of a JSON string in a R column?

Tags: r, json

I have a dataframe in R consisting of 6 columns. Two of those are JSON. I need only a small bit of the JSON string to appear in my final dataframe.

One of the JSON columns is called "question" and contains the question asked to the user. The other JSON column is called "answer_options" and contains the, you guessed it, answer options. However, in this particular subset there is always only one answer option. This is what the first two columns of the dataframe looks like:

```
item_number  question  answer_options  correct_answer
```

```
1  {"jsonTypeDefinition":"gameSelector","type":"OpenAnswer","question":{"mediaType":"text","content":"0 x 1"}}  {"layout":"Numpad","mediaType":"textAnswerOptions","answerOptions":["0"]}  0
2  {"jsonTypeDefinition":"gameSelector","type":"OpenAnswer","question":{"mediaType":"text","content":"1 x 1"}}  {"layout":"Numpad","mediaType":"textAnswerOptions","answerOptions":["1"]}  0
```

(Sorry for the bad column name formatting here, I tried a lot but couldn't make it cleaner. You can see in the table below what I tried to make)

And this is what I want it to look like:

```
item_number  question  answer_options  correct_answer
1            "0 x 1"   "0"             0
2            "1 x 1"   "1"             0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing

```
question = '{"jsonTypeDefinition":"gameSelector","type":"OpenAnswer","question":{"mediaType":"text","content":"0 x 1"}}'
```

we can use the package `jsonlite` and do

```
jsonlite::fromJSON(question)$question$content
# returns
# [1] "0 x 1"
```

Then you can replicate this for the whole column `question` of your data frame, e.g.

```
# dt denotes the data frame
vapply(1:nrow(dt), 
       function (k) jsonlite::fromJSON(dt$question[k])$question$content, 
       character(1))
```

And then similarly for the column `answer_options`.